# How to select some rows from one table and some rows in another with data in trid table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have four tables.

First and second have some standart content while third and fourth tables have content like this

first

```
id
name
```

second

```
id
count
```

third

```
id
color
```

fourth

```
id
id_third
id_first
```

And I select all from first with data from second, third and fourth tables.

```
SELECT id,
       name, 
       ifnull((select count from second s where s.id  = f.id),0) as page,
FROM first f
```

But how I can select ALL ROWS from third table where color . fourth.id_first={some id from first tbl}???

EDIT.

But i want select from some table not one value!!!

For example, this code doing what i want, but i have error, because i cant select more then one row in one tbl.. (see second line)

```
    select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS s.url,
        ifnull((select * from labels_data ld, labels l where ld.id=l.site_id and l.site_id=s.id),0) as labels,
        ifnull((select count from counter_li cl where cl.site_id = s.id order by date desc limit 1),0) as counter_li,
        ifnull((select count from counter_li cl where cl.site_id = s.id order by date desc limit 1 offset 1),0) as counter_li_before,
        last_check
    from sdata s
```

Comment: Read about "joins" in SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT id,
name, 
ifnull((select count from second s where s.id = f.id),0) as page, fourth.id_first
FROM first LEFT JOIN fourth ON first.id = fourth.id
Where fourth.id_first IN (Select id_first form fourth)
```

Answer (score 0):

See below SQL:

```
SELECT f.id,f.name,s.count, t.id, t.color, fo.id
FROM first f, second s, third t, fourth fo
WHERE f.id = s.id
AND fo.id_third = t.id
AND fo.id_first = fo.id
```